# Why doesn't the below OnboardingSupportFragment work in android?

Tags: android

I'm trying to implement the [OnboardingSupportFragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v17/leanback/app/OnboardingSupportFragment.html) in android but I'm not having much luck. Does anyone know of any examples where I can see where I might be going wrong?

I've overridden the base class and implemented all the methods I need to. But I can't seem to figure out how to launch the fragment from a fragment transaction.

In my Fragment activity:

```
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.add( R.id.dp_fragment_container, new DPOnboardingFragment());
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
```

OnBoardingFragment:

```
    @Override
    protected int getPageCount() {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    protected CharSequence getPageTitle(int pageIndex) {
        Log.d("GET PAGE TITLE", "REQUESTING THE PAGE TITLE");
        return "Welcome to the app!";
    }

    @Override
    protected CharSequence getPageDescription(int pageIndex) {
        Log.d("GET PAGE DESCRIPTION", "REQUESTING THE PAGE DESCRIPTION");
        return "Keen to get stuck in? Here's a couple of helpful tips to allow you to get the most out of the app";
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    protected View onCreateBackgroundView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container) {
        Log.d("GET PAGE BACKGROUND", "REQUESTING THE PAGE BACKGROUND");
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.onboarding_background, container);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    protected View onCreateContentView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.onboarding_note_created, container);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    protected View onCreateForegroundView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onFinishFragment() {
        super.onFinishFragment();
        // User has seen OnboardingFragment, so mark our SharedPreferences
        // flag as completed so that we don't show our OnboardingFragment
        // the next time the user launches the app.
        SharedPreferences.Editor sharedPreferencesEditor = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext()).edit();
        sharedPreferencesEditor.putBoolean(getString(R.string.is_first_launch), true);
        sharedPreferencesEditor.apply();
    }
}
```

Activity layout file:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:name=".DpOnboardingActivity"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/dp_fragment_container"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Leanback.Onboarding">
</FrameLayout>
```

I'd expect to see something like [this](https://developer.android.com/training/tv/playback/onboarding). But I'm just getting my activity background, so the fragment isn't being launched

Comment: OnboardingSupportFragment belongs to androidx.leanback. Leanback is used to build  Android TV apps